# Why is my list empty when i try to read it

Tags: asp.net

I am crating a web application in asp.net that has only textboxes and 2 buttons.
1 button to read from the textboxes and put into a list
2 button to read from the list and put it into TXT file
But when I try to read the list it shows as empty and just skips

This is the code:

```
{
    public List<Artikal> lista = new List<Artikal>();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var novi = new Artikal(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text, TextBox5.Text, TextBox6.Text, TextBox7.Text, TextBox8.Text, TextBox9.Text);
        lista.Add(novi);
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Artikal trenutan in lista)//This whole part is skiped bcs the lsit is empty
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("OVAJFAJL.txt"), true))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(string.Format(trenutan.ispis()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure if it would solve it, but you should probably instantiate lista inside Page_Load function

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read about [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web applications are state-less.  What this means in this context is that every request to this server-side code results in a *new* instance of the page class.

So this is re-created on every request:

```
public List<Artikal> lista = new List<Artikal>();
```

If you want data to persist across requests, you have to persist it somewhere.  Session state is a simple approach.  Page state or some client-side data can be used where appropriate, but this like isn't one of those cases.  A file is simple, but doesn't scale well in terms of race conditions and such.  A database is ideal because it also persists across web application restarts, which can happen at any time really.

Basically, you have to save your data somewhere.